# FXML file not loading after splash screen

Tags: java, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a problem adding a splash screen in my application. Below code is to run a splash screen at the start of the program in Start.java.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("WelcomeScreen.fxml"));
    Scene scene=new Scene(root);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

Below code is in the Welcomescreen.java which will set a timer and load the main fxml file.

```
class Screen extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainPage.fxml"));
                        Scene scene=new Scene(root);
                        Stage stage=new Stage();
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(WelcomeScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
                    }

                    rootPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();
                }
            });
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WelcomeScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        }
    }

}
```

}

After running, below stack trace is returned and I cant figure out where it went wrong.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
```

Comment: It seems you are importing the wrong `TextField` in your fxml? it should be  `javafx.scene.control.TextField`

Comment: Ohhh my, that was such a careless mistake by me. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change the import of your TextField in your fxml file.

Change

```
com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField
```

to

```
javafx.scene.control.TextField
```